# Cognito form using wrong form name in email subject line

Tags: email, cognito-forms

I created an account and am testing Cognito forms.  I created 1 form and then copied it to create two other forms.

The first form I created is called *Source Resonance Healing First Time Session*.  The third form I created, using the first as a starting place, has the name *Animal Communication Intake Form*.

The first form I tested as a live form with with actual data is the *Animal Communication Intake Form*.  In the email notification I received, the subject line is telling me that I have received a Source Resonance Healing form, but that is incorrect.

The forms list by their correct names while I'm on the Cognito form builder pages and when I go to embed them into a wordpress page on my site.

How do I fix this problem so that the email subject line is telling me and the customer the correct name of the form they filled out?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured it out.  It had to do with some of the fields on the left-hand side bar related to the SUBMIT button.  I had forgotten to edit them.  Now that I have, the problem is resolved.